# How to limit legend width with an expression in the title in tmap?

Tags: r, tmap

I have encountered some unexpected behavior in the `tmap` library and was wondering if there is a way around it. When producing a map with an expression in the legend title, the legend becomes too wide for some reason.

Here's some code to show what I mean:

```
library(tmap)
data("World")

# Produces normal legend window
tm_shape(World) +
  tm_polygons("HPI") +
  tm_layout(legend.bg.color = "#AAAAAA")

# Produces wide legend window
title <- expression(Local~G[i]^"*")
tm_shape(World) +
  tm_polygons("HPI", title = title) +
  tm_layout(legend.bg.color = "#AAAAAA")
```

I tried using the `legend.width` parameter of `tm_layout`, but that messes up the font and symbol size down the line. Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `tmap` just takes the unparsed length of your title as the `legend.width` and since your expression width is substantial due to sub/superscripts, you end up with a very wide frame. I couldn't find a way to prevent `tmap` from rescaling the text when `legend.width` is used. One solution would be to just remove the background color. Not ideal, but takes care of the weird width issue.

Comment: That's not an option for me unfortunately. There's a lot going on on my base map, so I need a background to make it readable.

Comment: Maybe you should consider `ggplot` then. Definitely more flexible when it comes to legend modifications.